# WPF using service reference but i cannot get authorized service client

Tags: c#, wpf, soap, service-reference

i have a http wsdl web service. I added this service to my wpf application on the vs2015. But there is something wrong with username and password. 
Network credentials also not work.

Application is throwing "**A security error was encountered when verifying the message**". This message is comes to me when i tried send request on the soap ui with wrong username/password.

```
public static void createTicket()
    {
        //NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(username,password);

        CALive.servicesClient client = new CALive.servicesClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;


        client.test("asd");

    }
```

Username and password is true and it working on the soapui. I tried add as web service and service references but both of them cannot authenticate to service.

Define different bindings to the change the credential types. But nothing changes.
Transport security mode is not working for the http service.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="servicesServiceSoapBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"  realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://WSDLSERVICE:8080/****/axis/services"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="servicesServiceSoapBinding"
        contract="CALive.services" name="servicesPort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My end point details;

```
<wsdl:service name="servicesService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:servicesServiceSoapBinding" name="servicesPort">
         <soap:address location="http://WSDLSERVICE:8080/****/axis/services"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I need any experiences peoples think. I waste my few days and really i can not get the solution.

```
    {System.ServiceModel.FaultException: A security error was encountered when verifying the message

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Aragorn.CALive.services.test(test request)
   at Aragorn.CALive.servicesClient.Aragorn.CALive.services.test(test request) in C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Monitoring\Monitoring\Service References\CALive\Reference.cs:line 2470
   at Aragorn.CALive.servicesClient.test(String test1) in C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Monitoring\Monitoring\Service References\CALive\Reference.cs:line 2476
   at Aragorn.CAService.createTicket() in C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Monitoring\Monitoring\CAService.cs:line 27
   at Aragorn.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Monitoring\Monitoring\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 81}
```

And i tried to connect to service using HttpClient same error is throwing

```
var TARGETURL = "http://********:8080/****/axis/services";
            XmlDocument requestBody = new XmlDocument();
            requestBody.LoadXml(@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ser='http://service.mn.com/'>
                                       <soapenv:Header/>
                                       <soapenv:Body>
                                          <ser:test>
                                             <test>test</test>
                                          </ser:test>
                                       </soapenv:Body>
                                    </soapenv:Envelope>");

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy("http://******:8080"),
                UseProxy = true,
            };
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri(TARGETURL+"/test"),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post
                };
                requestMessage.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", TARGETURL+"/test");
                requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(requestBody.InnerXml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName;
                // ... Use HttpClient.            
                var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Debug.WriteLine(content);
            }
```

One more question here. **If my password has special characters same as "* or !" is chars attempt to block the authenticaion?**

**RESOLVED :** 
If soap ui is connecting to the service with using ws-passwordtype is PasswordText then we should define wsse:Security tag in the header.

```
    <endpoint bla bla bla>
        <headers>
           <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
               <wsse:UsernameToken>
                   <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                   <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
               </wsse:UsernameToken>
         </wsse:Security>
   </headers>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Any help? problem not solved yet

Comment: Use the WCFTestClient.exe to load the wsdl and look at the service model config it generates. It might help.

Comment: There is no changes. WCFTestClient has the same error. I guess i missing some property to authentication. Soap UI how is succesful connect, which parameters or properties is using by soap ui